# Sqlite unrecognized token: "{"

Tags: python, sqlite

I might be missing something basic here but I cannot reference a variable name when inserting into a table. The same method works fine when creating the table.

Do these functions behave differently or am I missing something here?

````
current_date_a = datetime.now().strftime("%Y %m %d ")
current_date = "'" + current_date_a + "'"

todays_table_name = current_date

def create_table_all_address():
    c.execute(f'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {todays_table_name} (City REAL, Address REAL, Description REAL)')

def add_to_todays_addresses():

    input_1 = input("City.\n")
    input_2 = input("Address.\n")
    input_3 = input("Description.\n")

    a1 = input_1
    a2 = input_2
    a3 = input_3
    c.execute("INSERT INTO {todays_table_name} (City, Address, Description) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (a1, a2, a3))
    conn.commit()```
````

Comment: Did you mean to use a f string `f"{todays_table_name}"`? I would also stick with one form of formatting at a time, as you also used the `?` in the same string.

Comment: I might recommend letting the DB compute the current date rather than using string formatting.

Comment: Your second last line should have formatted sting

Comment: @chepner can you shed some light on how to achieve that, or point me to some resources on that?

Comment: Something like `'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strftime('%Y %m %d', date('now')) (City REAL, Address REAL, Description REAL);'''`. Then you have a completely static SQL command that won't be subject to any injection attacks. See, for example, https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/ for links to documentation for both `strftime` and `date`.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing variable names between `{}` in your string but in order to support this, it needs to be an f-string. . As of now, your strings are evaluated as it is without the variable values being substituted. Add an `f` before your insert string as mentioned in the comments:

```
c.execute(f"INSERT INTO {todays_table_name} (City, Address, Description) VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (a1, a2, a3))
```